# Geometry problemsolving

Tags: geometry

The Big and the Small Kingdom are both rectangular islands and divided into rectangular landscape. In each province there is a road that runs along one of the diagonals. On each island exist roads that make a closed route, which does not go through any point several times. The picture shows the Little Kingdom, which has six area:

[image]

The Great Kingdom has an odd number of landscapes. How many landscapes does the Great Empire have at least?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using kingdom and empire as being the same thing?

Comment: Are "landscape" and "province" and "area" the same thing? Are "Big" and "Great" the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> 9

One way to do this is:

> [image: solution]

Comment: Can you prove that there are no solutions for islands with 1, 3, 5, or 7 provinces?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> **5**, in case it's ok to not go through all squares.

In the general case

> We note that you can't possible have a path with less then 4 squares.

In the case where we don't have to go through all squares

> 5 is the lowest odd number higher then 4, so if we can find a solution, we have proof that this is the optimal solution. Luckily such a solution is easily found 
> [image]

sidenote:

> Just because the Big kingdom has less landscapes then the Small kingdom doesn't mean they're smaller.

Comment: Why is it impossible?

Comment: Let's not waste time on that. It is possible for odd numbers, the question is pointed at "what is the smallest [...]" which indicates that it does exist a solution. I can post one later if you want.

Comment: @algebra1 i'd like to see that to be honest, love to be wrong :) That said, i did provide a solution for the question you had.

Comment: Love your solution too, only it is not a correct one. In the text it says that every landscape has a road within it. I'll post a picture of a solution.

Comment: @algebra1 it is correct as written, sure you say each landscape has a road, but you only ask for a closed road, not one that uses all subroads